# Banner fadein fadeout plug in not working correctly JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am working on fade in-fadeout banner using jquery. i am getting an output but its not functioning correctly.

the first images fadeout but instead of second images to fade in.. directly the 3rd image pops in.

i checked the console, its showing no error.

please have a look at my code and help me accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>image slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="banner.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="banner_divs"></div>
        <div class="banner_divs"></div>
        <div class="banner_divs"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="banner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner{
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.banner_divs{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 400px;
    width: 700px;   
}
.banner_divs:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url("images/banner1.jpg");
}
.banner_divs:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url("images/banner2.jpg");
}
.banner_divs:nth-child(3){
    background-image: url("images/banner3.jpg");
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".banner_divs:not(:first)").hide();
    setInterval(function(){

        $(".banner_divs:first").fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo(".banner");

    },3000);

});
```

Comment: It would be really helpful, if some one points out the error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image following way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tid = setTimeout(timer, 3000);
    var $first = $('div:first', '.banner'),
    $last = $('div:last', '.banner');

    function timer() {
        $selected = $(".selected");
        $next = $selected.next('.banner_divs').length ? $selected.next('.banner_divs') : $first;
        $selected.removeClass("selected").fadeOut('fast');
        $next.addClass('selected').fadeIn('fast');
        tid = setTimeout(timer, 3000); 
    }
    function abortTimer() {
        clearTimeout(tid);
    }

});
```

And give `display:none;` to `.banner_divs` and use

```
.selected{
  display:block;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qotf5o7r/)**

[Reference Link](http://webdesignerhut.com/create-a-simple-jquery-image-slider/)

Comment: but can u tell me what is wrong in my given code. i need to make it clear, where i am going wrong??

Comment: @VishnuprasadVenugopal I think your code is working  man. https://jsfiddle.net/qotf5o7r/1/

Comment: But, when i check it in my browser, div 2 doesnt fadein and out.. it jumps directly to div 3. Is it maybe bcoz of the images i choose?

Comment: Try to check with this image

Comment: @VishnuprasadVenugopal Or Apply your images in this JSfiddle.